# How can I set Excels "Recalculate workbook before saving" in Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

In Powershell I can set the calculation option of an active Excel application to manual via:

```
$Excel = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
$xlCalculationManual = -4135
$Excel.Calculation = $xlCalculationManual
```

Is there something similar for Excel's "Recalculate workbook before saving"?
In VBA this can be achieved via

```
Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True
```

But I I need this in Powershell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's as simple as:

```
$Excel.CalculateBeforeSave = $true
```